# How to render nothing in json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm testing the following method:

```
  def destroy
    if @article.destroy
      render json nothing: true, message: "removed", status: :ok
    else
      render json: @article, message: "Failed to remove", status: :bad_request
    end
  end
```

The `render json nothing` line generates the error

> undefined method `json' for #Api::V1::ArticlesController:0x000000074f6148

Changing the line to `render json: message: "removed", status: :ok` makes no difference. How to render nothing?

**Update:** I tried the code below, which after deleting responds with `No response received`, while I would expect the message.

```
  def destroy
    if @article.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render nothing: true, message: "removed", status: :ok }
      end
    else
      render json: @article, message: "Failed to remove", status: :bad_request
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you really want to not render anything:

```
head :ok # or any another status, e.g. :created, :accepted, etc
```

as a parameter, you can add a status code or symbolic status ([statuses](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/10/13/list-of-rails-status-code-symbols/) or just in console `Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE`)

If you want to send a JSON message as response:

```
render json: { message: "removed" }, status: :ok
```

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to only to this for json?

Comment: It makes sense but for me this renders: `No response received` (it has removed the article). I would expect to see the message.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing it correctly, I added the code I used to the OP.

Comment: It responds with the error `too few arguments` referring to the line you suggested.

Comment: sorry, try this format.json { render json: { message: "removed"}, status: :ok }

Comment: Still `too few arguments`.

Comment: [HEAR YOU CAN FIND MORE](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/04/rendering-errors-in-json-with-rails/)

Answer (score 12):

Returning **HTTP 204 No Content** would make more sense if you don't want to return anything.

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 204
```

Or better just:

```
head :no_content
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I guess it's not possible to show a message (included as attribute in the serializer) at the same time?

Comment: render nothing is deprecated